# String objects and the heap

Tags: java, string, object, heap-memory

I am studying for the SCJP exam and I have a sample set of questions that I am working through.

One questions answer I am unsure about and was hoping someone here might be able to help me put this question to bed.

Here is the question,

Given:

```
11. public String makinStrings() {
12.    String s = "Fred";
13.    s = s + "47";
14.    s = s.substring(2, 5);
15.    s = s.toUpperCase();
16.    return s.toString();
17. }
```

How many String **objects** will be created when this method is invoked?

```
A. 1
B. 2
C. 3
D. 4
E. 5
F. 6
```

Thank you in advance for any help offered.
I greatly appriciate it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How many String objects will be created](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370593/how-many-string-objects-will-be-created)

Comment: The linked question even contains the exact same example.

Comment: True, it's an exact duplicate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's go through it line by line.

**Line 11**

An easy start, no strings created here.

**Line 12**

We're assigning the String `"Fred"` to `s`.  Although it looks like a String is created here, this string will live in the constant pool.  The [JVMS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/VMSpecTOC.doc.html) section [2.17.6 Creation of New Class Instances](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/Concepts.doc.html#19124) guarantees that the objects for string literals will *at latest* be created when the surrounding class is loaded, which by definition is *before the method is invoked*.  So no new string objects are created on this line.

**Line 13**

The literal string `"47"` is referenced, which again will have been created statically (as above).  However there's also the invocation of the `+` operator, which *will* create a new String in order to hold the result of the concatenation.  So that's the first string created.

**Line 14**

The `substring` method does indeed create a new String.  It shares the underlying character array with its parent - and so takes up hardly any extra memory - but since Strings are immutable, each different string representation requires a different `String` object.  (This is probably a gotcha - my first instinctive response was "ah, string created by substring are special" but of course it still has to create a new object).

**Line 15**

As above - the uppercase representation is different, so a new String must be created to hold the result.

**Line 16**

`Strings` override the `toString()` method to simply `return this` - hence no additional String is created.

**The scores on the doors**

By my count that's three String objects created during this method (with two of those objects sharing the same underlying character array, and with two pre-existing objects referenced for the string literals).

Comment: This answer reiterates the answer from this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370593/how-many-string-objects-will-be-created/7370800#7370800) so thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it would be possible to make the whole method into a single constant. It's possible, but the compiler isn't allowed to do so. Hence, there are 3 Strings created using 2 from the constant pool.

- Fred47
- ed4 (note: using same backing char[] as Fred47 though)
- ED4

2 and 3 are pretty easy as the compiler isn't allowed to optimize away this method invocations but the String is changed. Sting.toString() only returns `this`, so no new String either. But let's have a look on line 13 using disassembled byte code (`javap -c` is your friend here):

```
public java.lang.String makinStrings();
  Code:
   0:   ldc #16; //String Fred
   2:   astore_1
   3:   new #18; //class java/lang/StringBuilder
   6:   dup
   7:   aload_1
   8:   invokestatic    #20; //Method java/lang/String.valueOf:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
   11:  invokespecial   #26; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   14:  ldc #29; //String 47
   16:  invokevirtual   #31; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   19:  invokevirtual   #35; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
       // SNIP
}
```

As you see, "Fred" and "47" are loaded from the constant pool (`ldc`) to populate a StringBuilder that will finally become a String (StringBuilder.toString()).

So that makes 2 constant Strings plus 3 newly created Strings per method invocation.

Comment: Now that's a great answer, including the disassembled code, kudos.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say 3: the ones at lines 12, 13 and 15.

The reason why the line 14 (substring) doesn't create a new object is because of the internal way String works. Due to necessary optimization of substring (everything, including compiler, rely on substring), the String class has two pointers to the start and end of the string. Doing a substring only moves this pointers, and does not "copy" the object into a new one.

Comment: I concur. Although `String.toUpperCase()` is tricky - new `String` object is created only if there are any characters that need to be changed.

Comment: From reading this response [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370593/how-many-string-objects-will-be-created/7370800#7370800) 3 is indeed the answer, but on lines 13, 14 and 15.
Thanks for the response :)

Comment: @JarekPrzygódzki That's also what I think - substring does not change characters, but toUpperCase does (in this case anyway)

Comment: @Guillaume I do not concur with your reasoning. I only agree that the end result is correct.

Comment: .substring(..) does create new instance of String (the special case `s.substring(0, s.length())` is the only one that returns `this`). It uses the same char[] though. The package private constructor `String(int offset, int count, char[] value)` is used for this special purpose. Note: All publicly visible constructors taking a char[] will make a copy though.

Answer (score 0):

it will create the 5 objects of string

string is immutable class so for every new string it will create an object.

example

1. public String makinStrings() {

   1. String s = "Fred";  (this line create 1--- Fred string)
   2. s = s + "47";  (this line create 2- 47 string + 3- Fred47)
   3. s = s.substring(2, 5); (this line create 4-ed4)
   4. s = s.toUpperCase();(this line create 5-ED4)
   5. return s.toString();

So according to me it will create 5 object