# How many objects will we create on heap?

Tags: java, string

How many objects will be create for the following string on the heap:

```
String a = "abc";
String b = "def";
String c = "ghi";
String d = a+b+c
```

How many objects are created on the heap?

Comment: No way to know. Maybe 0 or 1

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370593/how-many-string-objects-will-be-created

Comment: Two, unless you count the internal objects in the StringBuilder instance.

Answer (score 1):

```
String a = "abc";  //String literal
String b = "def";  //String literal
String c = "ghi";  //String literal
String d = a+b+c   //String d = new StringBuilder(d).append(b).append(c).toString();
```

Note that [`StringBuilder#append`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) returns an *object*. Now it's easy for you to determine how many *objects* were created..

Also note that `toString` doesn't create a new String, it returns an already created one.

Comment: Does `new StringBuilder()` count as object?

Comment: So the objects would be `a`, `b`, `c`, an anonymous `StringBuilder`, and `d`?

Comment: @mathguy54 - You're not paying attention.  a, b, and c are literals.  They were created when the class was loaded.

Comment: LOL! StackOverflow, or how to get my degree without ever turning on my brain!

Comment: So there is only one object created - `StringBuilder`? Sorry for being ignorant...

Comment: @mathguy54 -- Two, the StringBuilder and the String value assigned to d.

Comment: dear i know after execution of complete programme their will be only on object create, but i want ot know, how many object will created in the heap memory with reference or without reference.