# How many string objects this program will create

Tags: java

Below is a Java program.

```
 public String makinStrings() {
 String s = “Fred”;
 s = s + “47”;
 s = s.substring(2, 5);
 s = s.toUpperCase();
 return s.toString();
 }
```

How can I find out how many String object is created in the String pool. I think there are 4 objects created which are - "Fred" , "Fred47" , "ed4" , "ED4". Is this correct assumption?

Comment: What version of java you are using

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How many String objects will be created](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370593/how-many-string-objects-will-be-created)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Java version 7:

- Due to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605/string-concatenation-concat-vs-operator) the **+** operator **creates new object**
- Due to [String reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22397861/why-is-string-immutable-in-java):

  - substring() **creates a new string** because String is immutable
  - toUpperCase() **creates a new string** because String is immutable
  - toString() **does not create a new string** but returning him itself

Assigning the "Fred" at the beginning won't create a new object since it will be taken from [literal pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_pool)

To sum up - **3 Strings has been created with every method call**. The string is an object so returning it does not create new - it is done by reference.

Comment: Why do you think `toUpperCase()` doesn't create a new string?

Comment: Of course it will - I've been suggested with no explicit information in the reference what was acually wrong. The question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370593/how-many-string-objects-will-be-created btw but I cannot flag it for some weird reason - I edited answer to the proper one (cause I also cannot delete it now... uhh). Thanks for the warning anyway